# Changing horizontal scrollbar color in tweetdeck

Tags: css

Tweetdeck has done something funny (and atrocious) with their horizontal scrollbar: the current position only appears on mouse hover. In contrast, the vertical columns have normal visible scrollbar handles.

I want to change the color of the horizontal scroll handle so it's visible, but I can't locate the relevant (I'm assuming) css style. What should I be looking for?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
.scroll-styled-h::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #71c9f8;
}
```